# spatial operations: how to buffer a polygon by area, not distance (from edge)

Tags: r, spatial

I want to buffer a spatial polygon **P** of area **A** so that the buffered feature **P_buffered** attains a defined area **A_buffered**. Function `sf::st_buffer` grows a feature by distance **d** (from edge) but not by area.

So far, I tried:

1. approximating **d** from some radial measure of **P** (radius of enclosing circle, diagonal of bbox), assuming that a radial increase by factor x will inflate the area by x² (roughly, depending on **P**'s rotational symmetry).
2. approximating **d** iteratively by interval halving

The accuracy of (1) varies with the feature's shape while (2) is too slow (at least my implementation of it)

I'd be very grateful for hints towards some package with a corresponding function (`pseudo::buffer_area()`) or codewise solution I seem to be overlooking.

Re. accessing other GIS executables from R, please note that the code has to run on a machine where only the availability of R packages can be taken as granted.

**example data**: `dput` dump of an example polygon class `sfc`for use with {sf}: https://gist.github.com/1O/bc3798468b48f19ab2533f16c99c2268

Comment: So you have some sample data of the polygons (so people do not have to create something from scratch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still suggest a while loop (your second approach)... perhals someone can tweak the growth/decline aloritm...

```
library(sf)

points = matrix(c(0,0,20,0,10,10,0,10,0,0),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
pts = list(points)
pl1 = st_polygon(pts)

# x = polygon
# y = desired buffer area
# z = allowed delte from area 
# example y = 100, z = 0.01, the bufferarea aloowed is bewteen 99 and 101
buffer_distance <- function(x, y, z) {
  buff_dist <- 1
  buffer_area <- st_area(st_buffer(x, buff_dist)) - st_area(x)
  while (!data.table::between(buffer_area, 
                              y - z * y,
                              y + z * y)) {
    if (buffer_area > y) {
      buff_dist <- buff_dist * (1 - y / st_area(st_buffer(x, buff_dist) ))
    } else {
      buff_dist <- buff_dist * (1 + y / st_area(st_buffer(x, buff_dist) ))
    }
    buffer_area <- st_area(st_buffer(x, buff_dist)) - st_area(x)
  }
  return(buff_dist)
}

buffer_distance(pl1, 100, 0.01)
#[1] 1.688372

st_area(st_buffer(pl1, buffer_distance(pl1, 100, 0.01))) - st_area(pl1)
# [1] 100.3634

plot(st_buffer(pl1, buffer_distance(pl1, 100, 0.01)))
plot(pl1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: And a brief word about `!data.table::between`, that doesn't seem to have a st_ equivalent, but I suppose the `!` in the context of `while`  here to help slow thinkers tease this out.

Comment: @Wimpel: definitely better than halving intervals. Unless some package-d function drops in, that'll be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a straightforward solution: **`sf` geometries can be scaled linearily by multiplying the geometry with a scalar** like:

```
## scale feature to triple linear extent (e.g. height):
zoom = 3
scaled_feature = zoom * feature

## scale feature to triple area:
scaled_feature = sqrt(zoom) * feature
```

The necessary buffer distance calculates, e.g., as the difference between inscribed circle radii of feature and scaled feature.

Example:

```
library(spData) ## contains sample data, e.g. London areas
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

## original feature (example: Kingston upon Thames in London,
## reprojected area-preserving Lambert (LCC Europe, EPSG 3034)
feature <- spData::lnd[1,] %>% st_transform(3034) %>% st_geometry 
zoom  <- sqrt(1.5) ## to scale area by 1.5
feature_zoomed <- feature * zoom
## get radial buffer distance as half the vertical difference
## between bounding boxes of inscribed circles):
buffer_distance <- 0.5 * (
    (feature_zoomed %>% st_inscribed_circle %>% st_bbox %>% .[c(4,2)] %>% dist) -
    (feature %>% st_inscribed_circle %>% st_bbox %>% .[c(4,2)] %>% dist)
)
feature_buffered <- st_buffer(feature, buffer_distance)
```

Accuracy will vary with vertex count and `st_buffer` settings (segments, join style, end cap style), breaking up multipolygons into polygons (`st_cast`) and `st_simplify`ing can help as well as feeding the initial buffer_distance into an approximation loop as demonstrated in @Wimpel 's answer.